# How to commit or rollback transaction in SpringMVC controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I am modify some old code and met a weird problme:

I need to **commit or rollback the transaction based on the service method return result in my controller method manually**. Below is the code that I want to archive.Is it possible to do it?

Note:
I know the most suitable way is to do some modification in the service code and let the service code determine rollback or commit.But due to some reasons I can't modify the service code,I can only modify the controller code.

```
@RequestMapping("processData")
public void processData(String id){
    String result = dataService(id);
    if("success".equals(result)){
        //commit transaction
    }else{
       //rollback transaction
    }
   //since there some other codes in controller method,so exception might not be a good choice
   //.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)` , and there's some more attributes, you can check spring documents.

Comment: Use exception is a choice,but if throw a exception,it will break the exists logic